# syslinux pxe boot reboots every few minutes

Tags: linux, yocto, syslinux

I am trying to achieve PXE Boot and install the Yocto Image on my intel Apollo Lake SoC.

What i did till now:

Created EFI/SYSLINUX Folder and placed syslinux.efi and ldlinux.e64, menu.c32 and in this folder created pxelinux.cfg folder and created "default file" with the following content:

```
serial 0 115200
ALLOWOPTIONS 1
SERIAL 0 115200
DEFAULT Serial console install
TIMEOUT 500
TOTALTIMEOUT 501
PROMPT 0
ui menu.c32
menu title Select kernel options and boot kernel
menu tabmsg Press [Tab] to edit, [Return] to select
LABEL Serial console install
KERNEL bzImage
APPEND initrd=initrd LABEL=install root=/dev/ram0  rootwait console=ttyS0,115200 console=tty0 console=ttyS0,115200
```

The system boots and displays the UI and starts loading bzImage over tftp and then while it is loading initrd image the system is reset.. It happens every time and I am thinking something related to timing may be every 5 minutes it restarts.

I am using syslinux 6.3.0 , what can be the issue here

Answer (score 0):

If SoC reboots each time after exactly same amount of time, I suppose that problem may be related to watchdog timer.
Check kernel output for something like:

```
iTCO_wdt: Intel TCO WatchDog Timer Driver v1.11
iTCO_wdt: Found a Apollo Lake SoC TCO device (Version=5, TCOBASE=0x0460)
iTCO_wdt: initialized. heartbeat=30 sec (nowayout=0)
```

There you can find more info about configuring watchdog: http://www.fit-pc.com/wiki/index.php/Linux_Mint:_Watchdog_configuration

Comment: No, the kernel is still not loaded at that time, it is still in the phase of loading initrd over tftp and store it in RAM

Comment: What happens if you don't specify initrd at all? Is kernel tries to boot?